# Can Sequel Create And Query Temp Tables

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am new to Sequel, but have a lot of background in SQL.
Getting frustrated with what I would call basic query functions not working. I am hoping it's a matter of just getting syntax correct.
I would like to create a temporary table, insert values into that table, then run a query against it.
In SQL I'd run this-

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP (CHRGCD VARCHAR)
INSERT INTO #TMP SELECT DISTINCT(CHRGCD) FROM PACPTCD WHERE CCTRMDT = '9999-01-01'

SELECT CHRGCD FROM PACPTCD 
WHERE CHRGCD NOT IN (SELECT CHRGCD FROM #TMP)
```

Can I do this all from Sequel or am I going to have to create a real table, run a separate script to populate it, the run the last part of the query?

The data in the table PACPTCD can have multiple entries for CHRGCD but the CCTRMDT can vary. I'm trying to find all instances where CHRGCD doesn't have a value of 9999-01-01. Seems to be the easiest way to do it. Open to suggestions on other ways to get the data.

Comment: Yes and no. In a query you can have nested selects. The internal select builds a temporary table of sorts and the outer select will select from that temporary table. something like SELECT * FROM (SELECT Fname, Lname FROM persons)

Comment: Your use of a temp table here appears to be a work-around for a deficiency in a particular SQL implementation. Have you tried simply expanding the first query into the second to see how the performance is?

Comment: Can't change the implementation and performance is terrible anyway. Can only face palm every time I find something that is just crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks user007.
I ended up changing the query.

```
 SELECT CHRGCD FROM PACPTCD
 WHERE CHRGCD NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CHRGC) FROM PACPTCD WHERE CCTRMDT='9999-01-01')
```

Dozen ways to do it. This one is the easiest. Even easier than my original.